# Difference between two lines ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, difference

I wanted to add the difference between two lines to a `ggplot2`.
In this example, between the lines of the two groups defined by `x2`. 
How can this be done?

```
y=rbinom(100,1,.4)
x1=rnorm(100, 3, 2)
x2=rbinom(100, 1, .7) 
sub = data.frame(y=y, x1=x1, x2=x2)

ggplot(sub, aes(x1, y, color = x2))   + 
      stat_smooth(method = "glm", family = binomial, formula = y ~ poly(x1,3))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two geom\_smooth() lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322590/difference-between-two-geom-smooth-lines)

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you should change in your code. First, inside `stat_smooth()` use `x` and `y` and not the actual variable names (function will know that your `x` values are `x1`). Second, wrap `x2` inside `factor()` to have two distinct colors.

```
ggplot(sub, aes(x=x1, y=y, color = factor(x2))) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "glm", family = binomial, formula = y ~ poly(x,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Didzis, thanks a lot for the answer. Now, do you know how to get the difference between both curves as well? Between green and red (if possible even with confidence interval? <br> Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be easier to calculate all this outside the ggplot() and then just plot those data.