# Difference between two geom_smooth() lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, difference, smoothing, gam

I made a plot for my data and am now I would like to have the difference in y for every x that was estimated by geom_smooth(). There is a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386555/difference-between-two-lines-ggplot2) which unfortunately has no answer. For example, how to get the differences for the following plot (data below):

[image: plot]

**EDIT**

**Two suggestions were made but I still don't know how to calculate the differences.**

**First suggestion** was to access the data from the ggplot object. I did so with

```
pb <- ggplot_build(p)
pb[["data"]][[1]]
```

That approach kind of works, but the data doesn't use the same x values for the groups. For example, the first x value of the first group is -3.21318853, but there is no x of -3.21318853 for the second group, hence, I can not calculate the difference in y for -3.21318853 between both groups

**Second suggestion** was to see what formula is used in geom_smooth(). The package description says that "*loess() is used for less than 1,000 observations; otherwise mgcv::gam() is used with formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")*". My N is more than 60,000, hence, gam is used by default. I am not familiar with gam; **can anyone provide a short answer how to calculate the difference between the two lines** considering the things just described?

R Code

```
library("ggplot2") # library ggplot
set.seed(1) # make example reproducible
n <- 5000 # set sample size
df <- data.frame(x= rnorm(n), g= factor(rep(c(0,1), n/2))) # generate data
df$y <- NA # include y in df
df$y[df$g== 0] <- df$x[df$g== 0]**2 + rnorm(sum(df$g== 0))*5 # y for group g= 0
df$y[df$g== 1] <-2 + df$x[df$g== 1]**2 + rnorm(sum(df$g== 1))*5 # y for g= 1 (with intercept 2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col= g)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(alpha= .1) # make a plot
```

Comment: I can think of two routes: find out the formula `geom_smooth()` uses to calculate the curve given the data, or save the ggplot object to a variable and try to access the data for the curve (not sure this can be done).

Comment: In addition to @sindri_baldur's comment, save your plot as `p`, then call `pb <- ggplot_build(p); pb$data[[1]]` This gives you the data that is used for plotting the lines and confidence intervals. Another option without saving the plot first is `layer_data(ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col= g)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(alpha= .1))`

Comment: @markus: That approach kind of works, but the data that is provided in pb[["data"]][[1]] after using pb <- ggplot_build(p) doesn't use the same x values for the groups. For example, the first x value of the firrst group is -3.21318853, but there is no x of -3.21318853 for the second group, hence, I can not calculate the difference in y for -3.21318853 between both groups.

Comment: @sindri_baldur Thank you. markus explained how to extract data from ggplot, which does not completly solve my problem. Could you describe the other approach that you suggest?

Comment: @schwantke It would just involve reading the ggplot documentation carefully and the calculate manually. I would still continue with clues given by markus... I think you have everything there. If doesn't work for groups, plot each group separately and extract the data in two steps.

Comment: I'd very much recommend *not* doing this via *ggplot2* if you want to have some sense of how uncertainty the estimated difference is. I would do this as a single GAM model using one of two types of smooth set up for difference smooths. As you get a model for all the data with uncertainties, you can propogate those uncertainties to the difference. I have two blog posts on the options for smooth set up: [Option 1](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/) and [Option 2](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/12/14/difference-splines-ii/)

Comment: @GavinSimpson Personally, I would prefer to do it properly with gam as you say but I have no experience in gam so far. I will read your blog posts and try to answer the question by myself. I will let you know and maybe you can have a look. Thank you for the links

Comment: I might get chance this evening to show you how to do this using the example data you provided. Feel free to ping me in a few days if I haven't added an answer below with a `gam()`-based solution.

Comment: @GavinSimpson If you have the chance to provide a code it would be great!

Comment: @schwantke I've now added an answer summarising the approach taken in the first blog post (Option 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, you really are better off doing this outside of *ggplot* and instead do it with a full model of the two smooths from which you can compute uncertainties on the difference, etc.

This is basically a short version of a [blog post](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/) that I wrote a year or so back.

### OP's exmaple data

```
set.seed(1) # make example reproducible
n <- 5000 # set sample size
df <- data.frame(x= rnorm(n), g= factor(rep(c(0,1), n/2))) # generate data
df$y <- NA # include y in df
df$y[df$g== 0] <- df$x[df$g== 0]**2 + rnorm(sum(df$g== 0))*5 # y for group g= 0
df$y[df$g== 1] <-2 + df$x[df$g== 1]**2 + rnorm(sum(df$g== 1))*5 # y for g= 1 (with intercept 2)
```

Start by fitting the model for the example data:

```
library("mgcv")
m <- gam(y ~ g + s(x, by = g), data = df, method = "REML")
```

Here I'm fitting a GAM with a factor-smooth interaction (the `by` bit) and for this model we need to also include `g` as a parametric effect as the group-specific smooths are both centred about 0 so we need to include the group means in the parametric part of the model.

Next we need a grid of data along the `x` variable at which we will estimate the difference between the two estimated smooths:

```
pdat <- with(df, expand.grid(x = seq(min(x), max(x), length = 200),
                            g = c(0,1)))
pdat <- transform(pdat, g = factor(g))
```

then we use this prediction data to generate the Xp matrix, which is a matrix that maps values of the covariates to values of the basis expansion for the smooths; we can manipulate this matrix to get the difference smooth that we want:

```
xp <- predict(m, newdata = pdat, type = "lpmatrix")
```

Next some code to identify which rows and columns in `xp` belong to the smooths for the respective levels of `g`; as there are only two levels and only a single smooth term in the model, this is entirely trivial but for more complex models this is needed and it is important to get the smooth component names right for the `grep()` bits to work.

```
## which cols of xp relate to splines of interest?
c1 <- grepl('g0', colnames(xp))
c2 <- grepl('g1', colnames(xp))
## which rows of xp relate to sites of interest?
r1 <- with(pdat, g == 0)
r2 <- with(pdat, g == 1)
```

Now we can difference the rows of `xp` for the pair of levels we are comparing

```
## difference rows of xp for data from comparison
X <- xp[r1, ] - xp[r2, ]
```

As we focus on the difference, we need to zero out all the column not associated with the selected pair of smooths, which includes any parametric terms.

```
## zero out cols of X related to splines for other lochs
X[, ! (c1 | c2)] <- 0
## zero out the parametric cols
X[, !grepl('^s\\(', colnames(xp))] <- 0
```

(In this example, these two lines do exactly the same thing, but in more complex examples both are needed.)

Now we have a matrix `X` which contains the difference between the two basis expansions for the pair of smooths we're interested in, but to get this in terms of fitted values of the response `y` we need to multiply this matrix by the vector of coefficients:

```
## difference between smooths
dif <- X %*% coef(m)
```

Now `dif` contains the difference between the two smooths.

We can use `X` again and covariance matrix of the model coefficients to compute the standard error of this difference and thence a 95% (in this case) confidence interval for the estimate difference.

```
## se of difference
se <- sqrt(rowSums((X %*% vcov(m)) * X))

## confidence interval on difference
crit <- qt(.975, df.residual(m))
upr <- dif + (crit * se)
lwr <- dif - (crit * se)
```

Note that here with the `vcov()` call we're using the empirical Bayesian covariance matrix but not the one corrected for having chosen the smoothness parameters. The function I show shortly allows you to account for this additional uncertainty via argument `unconditional = TRUE`.

Finally we gather the results and plot:

```
res <- data.frame(x = with(df, seq(min(x), max(x), length = 200)),
                  dif = dif, upr = upr, lwr = lwr)

ggplot(res, aes(x = x, y = dif)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, x = x), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

This produces

[image]

Which is consistent with an assessment that shows the model with the group-level smooths doesn't provide substantially better fit than a model with different group means but only single common smoother in `x`:

```
r$> m0 <- gam(y ~ g + s(x), data = df, method = "REML")

r$> AIC(m0, m)
         df      AIC
m0  9.68355 30277.93
m  14.70675 30285.02

r$> anova(m0, m, test = 'F')
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: y ~ g + s(x)
Model 2: y ~ g + s(x, by = g)
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev     Df Deviance      F Pr(>F)
1    4990.1     124372                              
2    4983.9     124298 6.1762   73.591 0.4781 0.8301
```

### Wrapping up

The blog post I mentioned has a function which wraps the steps above into a simple function, `smooth_diff()`:

```
smooth_diff <- function(model, newdata, f1, f2, var, alpha = 0.05,
                        unconditional = FALSE) {
    xp <- predict(model, newdata = newdata, type = 'lpmatrix')
    c1 <- grepl(f1, colnames(xp))
    c2 <- grepl(f2, colnames(xp))
    r1 <- newdata[[var]] == f1
    r2 <- newdata[[var]] == f2
    ## difference rows of xp for data from comparison
    X <- xp[r1, ] - xp[r2, ]
    ## zero out cols of X related to splines for other lochs
    X[, ! (c1 | c2)] <- 0
    ## zero out the parametric cols
    X[, !grepl('^s\\(', colnames(xp))] <- 0
    dif <- X %*% coef(model)
    se <- sqrt(rowSums((X %*% vcov(model, unconditional = unconditional)) * X))
    crit <- qt(alpha/2, df.residual(model), lower.tail = FALSE)
    upr <- dif + (crit * se)
    lwr <- dif - (crit * se)
    data.frame(pair = paste(f1, f2, sep = '-'),
               diff = dif,
               se = se,
               upper = upr,
               lower = lwr)
}
```

Using this function we can repeat the entire analysis and plot the difference with:

```
out <- smooth_diff(m, pdat, '0', '1', 'g')
out <- cbind(x = with(df, seq(min(x), max(x), length = 200)),
             out)

ggplot(out, aes(x = x, y = diff)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, x = x), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

I won't show the plot here as it is identical to that shown above except for the axis labels.

Answer (score 3):

Hi and welcome on Stack Overflow,

The first suggestion is good. To make the x-sequences match, you can interpolate the values in between using the [`approx`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/approxfun.html) function (in `stats`).

```
library("ggplot2") # library ggplot
set.seed(1) # make example reproducible
n <- 5000 # set sample size
df <- data.frame(x= rnorm(n), g= factor(rep(c(0,1), n/2))) # generate data
df$y <- NA # include y in df
df$y[df$g== 0] <- df$x[df$g== 0]**2 + rnorm(sum(df$g== 0))*5 # y for group g= 0
df$y[df$g== 1] <-2 + df$x[df$g== 1]**2 + rnorm(sum(df$g== 1))*5 # y for g= 1 (with intercept 2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col= g)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(alpha= .1) # make a plot
pb <- ggplot_build(p) # Get computed data

data.of.g1 <- pb[['data']][[1]][pb[['data']][[1]]$group == 1, ] # Extract info for group 1
data.of.g2 <- pb[['data']][[1]][pb[['data']][[1]]$group == 2, ] # Extract info for group 2

xlimit.inf <- max(min(data.of.g1$x), min(data.of.g2$x)) # Get the minimum X the two smoothed data have in common
xlimit.sup <- min(max(data.of.g1$x), max(data.of.g2$x)) # Get the maximum X
xseq <- seq(xlimit.inf, xlimit.sup, 0.01) # Sequence of X value (you can use bigger/smaller step size)

# Based on data from group 1 and group 2, interpolates linearly for all the values in `xseq`
y.g1 <- approx(x = data.of.g1$x, y = data.of.g1$y, xout = xseq)
y.g2 <- approx(x = data.of.g2$x, y = data.of.g2$y, xout = xseq)

difference <- data.frame(x = xseq, dy = abs(y.g1$y - y.g2$y)) # Compute the difference
ggplot(difference, aes(x = x, y = dy)) + geom_line() # Make the plot
```

Output:
[image: Expected output]

Comment: The think I like about that approach is that it does not matter what method was used inside of geom_smooth, e.g. loess or gam. Thank you.